# What are the advantages of using axios over the built in http client in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

NodeJS has a built in package for making http requests. The package seems to be easy to use and makes it easy to handle asynchronous responses via callbacks. Still I see everyone using third party http packages like `axios`.

What are the advantages of using `axios` compared to the built in `http` package?

Answer (score 2):

Well, Axios is a well known open source package (MIT licensing), this means it has the whole community finding issues and fixing it. It gets over 400K downloads for week an is ready to use. If you build one your self you would have to take the time to built it, test it and would have only your self and the team involved in the development to maintain, even if you make it open source, it wold take time to get all issue and etc.